# Variable substitution within a string

Tags: javascript, str-replace, variable-substitution

I'm trying to come up with some very reusable code that will look up and perform variable substitutions within a string.

The example string below contains a `$$` reference to a variable. Format is `varname.key`.

I want the `subText()` function to be reusable. The issue I'm having is `repvars` themselves can require substitution. The code hasn't finished substituting the example text and I'm asking it to substitute the `repvars.cr` by calling the same function. This seems to through it off. I'm saying that because if I do it separately in works.

```
var exampleText = "A string of unlimited length with various variable substitutions included $$repvars.cr$$";
    var repvars = {
        cr: 'Copyright for this is $$repvars.year$$',
        year: '2019'
    }

function subText(text) {
    var subVars = findSubs(text);
    return makeSubs(text, subVars);
}

function findSubs(theText) {
    var subarr = [];
    while (theText.indexOf('$$') > -1) {
        theText = theText.substring(theText.indexOf('$$') + 2);
        subarr.push(theText.substring(0, theText.indexOf('$$')));
        theText = theText.substring(theText.indexOf('$$') + 2);
    }
    return subarr;
}

function makeSubs(text, subs) {
    for (var s = 0; s < subs.length; s++) {
        var subst = getSubVal(subs[s]);
        text = text.split("$$" + subs[s] + "$$").join(subst);
    }
    return text;
}

function getSubVal(subvar) {
    var subspl = subvar.split('.');
    switch (subspl[0]) {
        default:
            return processRepVar(subspl[1]);
    }
}

function processRepVar(rvName) {
    var data = getRepVarData(rvName);
 if(data.indexOf('$$') > -1) {
   subText(data);
 } else {
  return data; 
 }
}

function getRepVars() {
    return repvars;
}

function getRepVarData(key) {
    return getRepVars()[key];
}

subText(exampleText);
```

Answer (score 2):

Aren't you just missing a `return` here?

```
function processRepVar(rvName) {
    var data = getRepVarData(rvName);
 if(data.indexOf('$$') > -1) {
   subText(data);
 } else {
  return data; 
 }
}
```

Changing `subText(data)` to `return subText(data);` makes your code work for me.

Working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uzxno754/

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried regular expressions for this?

```js
function replace(str, data) {
  let re = /\$\$(\w+)\$\$/g;
  
  while (re.test(str))
    str = str.replace(re, (_, w) => data[w]);
    
  return str;
}

//

var exampleText = "A string with variables $$cr$$";

var repvars = {
  cr: 'Copyright for this is $$year$$',
  year: '2019'
}

console.log(replace(exampleText, repvars))
```

Basically, this repeatedly replaces `$$...$$` things in a string until there are no more.